# Adding non-zero elements of a matrix in R

Tags: r, loops, matrix, sum, element

I have a matrix 'w' with zero and non-zero elements. I want to print out the index of the non-zero elements in the matrix, print the values of each non-zero element and get the sum of the non-zero elements in the matrix. I know I can print the index of non-zero elements using

`which(w!=0, arr.ind=TRUE)`

I am trying to print the values of the non-zero elements in 'w' matrix but the code is returning the whole matrix instead of only the non-zero elements.

```
for(i in 1:36){
for(j in 1:36){
    if(w[i,j]!=0){
    print (w);
    }
    }
    }
```

I want to take out the non-zero elements in 'w' so that I can print the sum.

Comment: In your loop, I guess `print(w[i,j])` would print only non-zero elements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To print the non-zero values:

```
w[w != 0]
```

To sum:

```
sum(w[w !=0 ])
```

ExperimenteR is of course correct that this will yield the same result as `sum(w)`.